# Acronym or abreviaturas(portuguese) don't appear

Tags: acronyms, glossary

I have this segment in my `pei.tex`:

```
\include{./tex/acronimos}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Abreviaturas}
%\setglossary{glodelim={\noexpand}}
%\setglossary{glsnumformat=ignore}
\printglossaries
\addcontentsline {toc} {chapter} {Abreviaturas}
```

In `tex` I have `acronimos` and this:

```
\newacronym{acc}{ACC}{Accelerometer}
\newacronym{acid}{ACID}{Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability}
...
```

but it does not appear in the generated pdf. Can someone offer advice towards a solution ?

Comment: Welcome! Why `\include`? Use `\input`. Anyway, you should extend your code to a minimal example that can be run through LaTeX.

Comment: i change to input but still didn't get in pdf